# MySQL Search matching multiple keywords

Tags: mysql, select

Looking for posts matching two keywords (both, not just one of them).

I guess the reason why the following MySQL query returns no matches is that keywords matching "climate" and keywords matching "recycling" are not the same rows in the t_keywords table. How would you proceed?

```
SELECT t_posts.id, t_posts.title
FROM t_posts, t_keywords, t_posts_keywords
WHERE t_posts.id = t_posts_keywords.id_post
AND t_keywords.id = t_posts_keywords.id_keyword
AND t_keywords.keyword = "climate"
AND t_keywords.keyword = "recycling"
GROUP BY t_posts.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t_posts.id, t_posts.title
FROM t_posts, t_keywords, t_posts_keywords
WHERE t_posts.id = t_posts_keywords.id_post
AND t_keywords.id = t_posts_keywords.id_keyword
AND t_keywords.keyword IN ('climate', 'recycling')
GROUP BY t_posts.id HAVING count(t_keywords.id) = 2
```

You already group by post, so all you need is to check that given post has two rows in original data, one with each keyword - which is what HAVING is for. If you have variable number of keywords to match, then "2" has to be variable too, replaced with right count by application.

Comment: Works fine, thanks! Is it also possible with WHERE t_keywords.keyword LIKE "climate%" (LIKE instead of =)

Comment: It is possible with "AND (t_keywords.keyword LIKE 'climate%' OR t_keywords.keyword LIKE 'recycling%')" (IN is only simplified OR), but if 'climate%' matches more than one keyword, then the "= 2" part might not work, so you might change it to " >= 2", but that would return rows matching 'climate1' and 'climate2' without ever touching 'recycling'

Answer (score 1):

Back to the basics: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

If your keyword is "climate" - what means your result for t_keywords.keyword = "climate" operation is TRUE, the next part of your code (t_keywords.keyword = "recycling") will always FALSE.
TRUE AND FALSE always means FALSE - what means your select will always empty.

You can use IN operator or you can use () and OR like:

```
WHERE t_posts.id = t_posts_keywords.id_post
AND t_keywords.id = t_posts_keywords.id_keyword
AND (t_keywords.keyword = "climate" OR t_keywords.keyword = "recycling")
GROUP BY t_posts.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN`. Like this:

```
SELECT t_posts.id, t_posts.title
FROM t_posts, t_keywords, t_posts_keywords
WHERE t_posts.id = t_posts_keywords.id_post
AND t_keywords.id = t_posts_keywords.id_keyword
AND t_keywords.keyword IN("climate","recycling")
GROUP BY t_posts.id
```

You can also use `OR` between. Like this:

```
SELECT t_posts.id, t_posts.title
FROM t_posts, t_keywords, t_posts_keywords
WHERE t_posts.id = t_posts_keywords.id_post
AND t_keywords.id = t_posts_keywords.id_keyword
AND 
(
   t_keywords.keyword ="climate" OR
   t_keywords.keyword ="recycling"
)
GROUP BY t_posts.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mate:

```
SELECT
    t_posts.id, t_posts.title
FROM
    t_posts
    INNER JOIN t_posts_keywords ON t_posts_keywords.id_post = t_posts.id
    INNER JOIN t_keywords ON t_keywords.id = t_posts_keywords.id_keyword
WHERE
    t_keywords.keyword IN ('climate', 'recycling');
```

**E:** This is based on your given query to find records from t_keywords with a keyword value of 'climate' or 'recycling' which is linked into t_posts_keywords pivot table to t_posts for output.

Comment: Thanks! Query looks much better with such INNER JOIN. But to answer my question, it would need GROUP BY t_jobs.id HAVING count(t_keywords.id) = 2 at the end, as user1786423 proposed in his answer

Comment: @Benj. thanks for the response ;) Oh I see, where would that t_jobs will come from? I don't see it in the question and sample query you're using. Anyways, thanks tho~

Comment: Sorry, not t_jobs but t_posts! So, I need GROUP BY t_posts.id HAVING count(t_keywords.id) = 2 at the end of the query. If not, I don't get matches for both keywords (that was my question), but matches for one keyword OR the other. Thanks again for your quick answer.